how to paint texture when uv face is scaled down to point

So I have this ico sphere that every face is scaled down to point in uv.
And the uv this perfectly align to every pixel for a 512x512 texture.
But seems I can't paint texture correctly?

Blender file :


Hello, maybe you have overlapping faces in the UV Editor, also maybe inverted normals? Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Hi , I uploaded the blender file.

I'm not sure why it doesn't work but if you unwrap again with the Smart UV Project for example it will work fine

You can then just paint the image in the Image Editor without worrying about landmarks in the 3d view if that is what you wanted. Forcing the UV to such a tiny place and then using view projection is probably incurring a graphics issue - the 3d view us4es ray casting for the painting, and this might be very difficult. Did you also try the same thing with a plane? Should be easier to contrast the same idea of one pixel per face.
